# Setting Variable From Within RxJava Chain

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am using the [`ReactiveLocation` library](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation). Basically, I want to get a location within 4 seconds of sufficient accuracy. If a location of sufficient accuracy hasn't been received in that time but other locations have then return the highest accuracy location.

As soon as a location of sufficient accuracy is received then that is returned and the observable is completed.

I will post the code of what I am trying. I could be, and probably am, going about this the wrong way.

```
LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(MIN_DISTANCE_UPDATE_INTERVAL);

    if ( expirationSeconds != null )
        request.setExpirationDuration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(expirationSeconds));

    ReactiveLocationProvider locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(context);
    Observable<Location> observable = locationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(request)
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Location location) {
                        if ( mostAccurateLocation == null )
                            mostAccurateLocation = location;

                        if ( location.getAccuracy() < mostAccurateLocation.getAccuracy() )
                            mostAccurateLocation = location;
                    }
                })
                .filter(new Func1<Location, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(Location location) {
                        return location.getAccuracy() < sufficientAccuracy ;
                    }
                });

    if ( expirationSeconds != null )
        observable = observable.timeout( expirationSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just(mostAccurateLocation), backgroundThread );

    return observable.firstOrDefault(mostAccurateLocation)
                     .doOnNext(new Action1<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Location location) {
                            lastLocation = location;
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. The timeout was kicking in but obviously, the observable being initiated by the timeout was using the `mostAccurateLocation` variable as it was at the time of observable creation.

To fix this I used the `Observable.defer` pattern so it would only create the `Observable<Location>` when it was subscribed to.

```
    if ( expirationSeconds != null ) {
        Observable<Location> mostAccurateLocationObservable = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Location>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Location> call() {
                return Observable.just(mostAccurateLocation);
            }
        });

        observable = observable.timeout( expirationSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS, mostAccurateLocationObservable, backgroundThread );
    }
```